# How to add a line break in the content of XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to add a line break in the content of XML used for C# .Net documentation,

```
<summary>
    <example>
        <para> content </para>
        (want to add a line break here)
        <code> content </code>
    </example>
</summary>
```

How can I add it? 
Thanks in advance.
BTW, < para /> not work for me.

Comment: I think the <para> tag may be the problem, have you tried removing it

Comment: by adding the  <br /> allows the line to break, thus creating a new line!

Comment: @DanD. I have another question. How can i add the line between <para> and <code>. I have tried <para/>, but failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br/>` tag

```
<summary>
    <example>
        <para>
            <code>
                a(want to add a line break here)<br/>
                b
            </code>
        </para>
    </example>
</summary>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a newline in the actual file use the #10; entity. The 
 element will be interpreted by a browser, not a simple XML display tool for formatting.